# Which AWS plan is proper for me?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vps, dedicated-server

I use a dedicated server with 2gb ram, 6ghz (Dual Xeon) cpu and 500gb Bandwith (actually I need %30 of this bandwith) and 120 gb storage capacity (and I need only 50-60 gb capacity)
I have a Java application, my app visited by approximately 2000 users everyday (these user don't upload or download file, only database operations).
I want to migrate to aws but I am a little confused. Amazon has many plans and I can't choose which plan is proper for me?
I just want to have a stable server solution.

Comment: AWS doesn't have "plans". You pay for what you use. If you use a server, you pay on an hourly basis. If that server has storage, you pay per gigabyte on an hourly basis. If it uses bandwidth, you pay at something like $0.10/GB. etc. etc. etc. If this wasn't clear from the AWS site, you probably should stick with just a simpler dedicated server.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your server 24/7, you want the Heavy Utilization Reserved Instance for the type of instance you want to run. They are by far the most economical, and there isn't really any debating for that.

A direct comparison of instance type to what you're running in dedicated isn't possible, you'll have to pick if you'd rather have right-sized RAM or right-sized CPU. Only you can answer that.

**Right sized CPU**: c1.medium, m1.large, m2.xlarge
**Right sized RAM**: m1.medium